# Working with SMS and ports in Android

Tags: android, sms

1. Is it possible to find to which port was the SMS sent(as I understand getOriginatingAddress returns only number)?
2. How can I send SMS to a specific port from emulator?

The main problem is that port number and phone number which emulator has are the same.

Comment: Is it that you want to send SMS messages from an app? Please clarify your question.

Comment: I send SMS from DDMS, there I can specify only number but not destination port

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Launch another instance of emulator. The port number is displayed in the window title.

To send SMS to custom port use [this method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html#sendDataMessage%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20short,%20byte%5B%5D,%20android.app.PendingIntent,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29).

Comment: That is the problem. I need to specify both number and port. For emulator default 5554 is both port and number. So if I send SMS to emulator with number 5554, it receives it, but I also need to specify a port.

Comment: @Sergey There's another overloaded method where the port number is not required. And to test with two emulator instances, each one has it own phone number and port.

Answer (score 0):

My quick guide if you wanna check how to send sms among devices: http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/07/07/sending-messages-among-devices/